# Add a custom option to a page in backend

Tags: posts, pages, options

I want to add an option in pages' backend.
Searching on the internet I find guides on how to create a backend page dedicated to options esclusively. I'd like to add an option to a page instead, under the page content editor (or on the right sidebar).
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

To add a option box for a page or post, you need to use `add_meta_boxes` action.

```
 //Register Meta Box
 function register_meta_box() {
      add_meta_box(
          'meta-box-id',
          __( 'MetaBox Title', 'text-domain' ), 
          'meta_box_callback', 
          'post', 
          'advanced', 
          'high' 
     );
 }
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'register_meta_box');

  //Add field
  function meta_box_callback( $post_id ) {

 $output = '<label for="title_field">'. esc_html__('Title Field', 'text-domain') .'</label>';
 $title_field = get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'title_field', true );
 $output .= '<input type="text" name="title_field" id="title_field" class="title_field" value="'. esc_attr($title_field) .'" />';

     echo $output;
 }

// Save meta field
add_action('save_post', 'save_meta_field');

function save_meta_field($post_id){
      // Check nonce, sanitize field
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'title_field', $_POST['title_field']);
}
```

The `add_meta_box()` parameters must be set to fit your needs (advanced and 'high'), and of course the field name and the screen(s) where your want the box to appears.

You will find more details about `add_meta_boxes` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think, the easiest way for you is:
[Advanced custom fields plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I'd like to add it myself