# Add option in th event calendar

Tags: events, plugin-events-calendar

I have a stuck that make me headache so much, as you see picture, this is my result when i add option to event.

[image]

I'm updated code in: `wp-content/theme/mytheme/lib/metabox/function.php`

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id' => 'event_date_option',
'title' => __( 'Event options', 'mytheme' ),
'pages' => array( Custom_Posts_Type_Event::POST_TYPE ), // Post type
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Event type:', 'mytheme' ),
        'desc' => __( 'Choose event type', 'mytheme' ),
        'id' => SHORTNAME . Widget_Event::EVENT_INTERVAL_META_KEY,
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            array( 'value'=>"n" , 'name' => __( 'Normal', 'mytheme' ) ),
            array( 'value'=>"c" , 'name' => __( 'Comunity', 'mytheme' ) ),
        ),
    )
```

It's show in event post, but i don't know how to save when add new event OR when i'm update event post. Please help me, thank you!

Ahh, i save it in database with new table like: ID_POST, VALUE

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add use function for update event options of event for hint please : [Click hear](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save you custom field with the `save_post` action.

You'll find the process to add and save meta boxes with this question : [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246042/58141)

Hope it helps